# Text Label in Tkinter not Updating - Windows 7

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make use of text labels in a simple Tkinter GUI running on Windows 7.  I cannot get the text labels to update when I use the set method of their associated StringVars.  The following code will work fine in Mac OS, but in Windows 7 the label is completely blank.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import time

def done():
    print 'called'
    root.after_cancel(fun)
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

def myloop():
    global fun
    tst.set(str(time.time()))    
    fun = root.after(100,myloop)

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title('Title')

tst = Tk.StringVar()
lbl = Tk.Label(master=root,textvariable=tst)
lbl.pack(side=Tk.TOP)

txt = Tk.Text(master=root)
txt.insert(Tk.INSERT,'Test2')
txt.pack()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",done)
fun = root.after(100,myloop)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tested it with Python2.7 , Python2.6 and Python2.5 on my Windows 7 and it works. The time updates. Which Python version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your program and it updates the StringVar flawlessly. The only reason I think it may not work is because you are not setting the master of the `StringVar`, so you should replace that statement with `tst = Tk.StringVar(root)`.

However, you can get rid of the `StringVar` since the text is an option of the label configuration, and you can change it with the `config` method:

```
def myloop():
    global fun
    lbl.config(text=time.time())
    fun = root.after(100,myloop)

# ...
lbl = Tk.Label(master=root)
lbl.pack(side=Tk.TOP)
```